# How to write PL/SQL packages for all tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have 5 tables in schema (t1, t2, t3, t4, t5)

I want to use data dictionary to write DML packages for all tables in schema with one code, not to write one by one.

I couldn't find any example on google.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examples you're looking for are related to **dynamic SQL**. It will work (if you use it correctly), but doesn't scale at all. What if `t6` or `t7` appear?

What I meant to say is that data model looks *wrong*, if there are several tables which - apparently - look the same as you can reuse the same code on all of them. I'd suggest you to merge all those tables into one, by adding additional column which will distinguish rows (i.e. what `t1` table's rows represent, what `t2` table's rows represent etc.).

You'll have to put some effort into it, but it'll pay off in long term.

Comment: You *can* do that, but it will require a lot of pain on your side. Mind you, the whole package code written dynamically! All single quotes to be escaped, all parenthesis that have to match, all table and column names properly spelled (as during compilation you won't get any errors as all the code will be treated as a *string*). A true nightmare, and I don't intend to participate in it.

Comment: Ah. You deleted all comments so now it looks as if I'm talking to myself. Never mind. Just don't do that.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted comments. I didn't see that you replied me, I don't know why?. I understood now. Thank you so much!